# my eclipse is throwing a nosuchmethodException for the springFramework plugin

Tags: java, eclipse

My Eclipse is throwing this error it says is in the org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons. 
What am I missing? 
I have springtools 4 installed. https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-4-spring-boot-aka-spring-tool-suite-4

The eclipse session data is:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.9.0.I20180906-0745 
java.version=1.8.0_191
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product
 org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
```

My stack trace is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaSourceViewer.doUpdateCodeMinings()
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2130)
at org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons.STS4LanguageClientImpl.updateHighlightAnnotations(STS4LanguageClientImpl.java:181)
at org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons.STS4LanguageClientImpl.access$0(STS4LanguageClientImpl.java:169)
at org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons.STS4LanguageClientImpl$UpdateHighlights.updateSourceViewer(STS4LanguageClientImpl.java:154)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:270)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:270)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons.STS4LanguageClientImpl$UpdateHighlights.runInUIThread(STS4LanguageClientImpl.java:139)
at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob.lambda$0(UIJob.java:98)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:40)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:185)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3933)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3564)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:821)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:797)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.log.EventDetailsDialog.open(EventDetailsDialog.java:191)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.log.EventDetailsDialogAction.run(EventDetailsDialogAction.java:102)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.log.LogView.lambda$2(LogView.java:565)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$1.run(StructuredViewer.java:833)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil.lambda$0(JFaceUtil.java:47)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:176)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireDoubleClick(StructuredViewer.java:830)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.handleDoubleSelect(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1518)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetDefaultSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1260)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireDefaultSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:252)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$0(OpenStrategy.java:250)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:309)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4145)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1055)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3958)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3561)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:628)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:563)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:151)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:199)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:391)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:246)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to delete the spring configuration I had installed and then find the newer plugin and install that instead.